# T-SQL How to pass all paramters from a stored procedure to another without knowing details

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We have a number of standard stored procedures in our software that we sometimes get to customize some for customers.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME
    @param1 int, @param2 int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @spName NVARCHAR(255)
    SET @spName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
    SET @spName = 'dbo.' + @spName + '_Custom'

    IF OBJECT_ID (@spname , N'P') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql @spName, N'@param1 int, @param2 int', @param1, @param2
        RETURN
    END
    ...
END
```

This works fine, but I have to rewrite in every stored procedure to adapt the parameters list.

I'm trying to create a mechanism to call the custom version in case it exists, passing all the parameters.

I'd like to be able to use the same code for all procedures.

```
DECLARE @spParamtersList TABLE ([name] nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @spParamtersList
    SELECT [name] 
    FROM sys.parameters 
    WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@spName)

DECLARE @strParameters varchar(MAX) = SELECT @strParameters = COALESCE(@strParameters + ',' + [name], [name]) FROM @spParamtersList
```

This works fine, but now i have to call the custom stored procedures, I tried:

```
set @strSQL = N'EXEC ' + @SpName + ' ' + @strParameters
EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL
```

The string is correct:

*'EXEC PROCEDURE_NAME_Custom @param1, @param2'*

But it doesn't work.

Comment: *"But it doesn't work."* doesn't tell us anything. This, however, sounds like a design flaw and/or [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), if I am honest.

Comment: Pardon me, but what does this achieve? You are using your proc to gather its parameters and then dynamically run the `same` proc with the `same` parameters?

Comment: Agreed, I can't see a reason why you would eve do this, and if you really did need to do this then a solution based on C# or Python would probably be far better. It could gather info from system tables such as `sys.procedures` and `sys.parameters` and pass everything through correctly

Comment: It is not the SAME sproc, it is a custom one. 
We have many database on client server, all are the same and have the same sproc, but sometimes a client ask to do something different in the specific sproc so i'd want to create a sproc_custom, with same name and parameters

Comment: One option is to just add all the parameters to both stored procedures, then dynamically call the one you want. You don't need dynamic SQL for that, you can just do `EXEC @procName @param1 = @param1...` and pass all parameters